# MongoDB query array of objects in collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

I have a collection, and inside this collection I have an array of objects called `Degrees`.

This array contains objects with keys `{Uni:'',Level:'',Degree:''}`, I want to be able to add to a parameter object the ability to find any document with a degree where `level = 'BS'`, for example, regardless of what the other fields in the object contain.

I have tried so far:

```js
{
  $elemMatch: {
    $eq: {
      Uni: {
        $exists: true,
        
      },
      Level: "BS",
      Degree: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it has not worked, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You can query the fields of the documents in the embedded array directly.

If your documents look something like

```
{
 _id:ObjectId("..."),
 Name: "",
 degrees: [
           {Uni:"",
            Level:"BS",
            Degree:""}
          ]
 }
```

You could return all documents that contain at least one 'BS' level degree with

```
db.collection.find({"degrees.Level":"BS"})
```

Answer (score 3):

The *$elemMatch* operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

```
{ <field>: { $elemMatch: { <query1>, <query2>, ... } } }
```

I guess this should work for you :

```
db.collection.find({Degrees: {$elemMatch: {level:'BS'}}})
```

Don't forget to replace collection with ur model name. :)

Do checkout $elemMatch documetation here : [mongoDb $elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, and assuming your collection is called `degrees`, it should be as simple as:

```
// From the mongo shell:
db.degrees.find({ Level: 'BS' });

// From javascript (assuming node's native driver):
db.collection('degrees').find({ Level: 'BS' });
```

If you're interested in only the first result then you can use the following:

```
// From the mongo shell:
db.degrees.findOne({ Level: 'BS' });

// From javascript:
db.collection('degrees').findOne({ Level: 'BS' });
```